# wAsync Client can't reconnect to Atmosphere after disconnect

Tags: java, websocket, jersey, atmosphere

I'm developing a RESTful pub sub application, using `@Subscribe` and `@Publish` annotation.

After server crash or network failure, wAsync fires `Event.CLOSE` event but it isn't able to reconnect with atmosphere server. Channel was created but existent clients not suscribed to it. Nevertheless, new clients can suscribe to that channel.

Note that I haven't any log.

**Software stack**

- Tomcat 7.0.62
- Jersey 1.19
- Atmosphere 2.4.2
- wAsync 2.1.2

My **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.mesview.rest
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType</param-name>
        <param-value>application/json</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Jersey implementation**

```
@Path("metallica")
public class MetallicaService {

    @GET
    @Path("/suscripcion")
    @Subscribe(value = "metallica", timeout = -1)
    public String handshake() {
        return null;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Publish("metallica")
    public String createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Metallica -- Track saved : " + track;
        //return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And finally, the **client**

```
public class MetallicaClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final Client client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient();

        final RequestBuilder request = client.newRequestBuilder()
                .method(Request.METHOD.GET)
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/metallica/suscripcion")
                .encoder(new Encoder<String, Reader>() {        // Stream the request body
                    @Override
                    public Reader encode(String s) {
                        System.out.println("Encode: " + s);
                        return new StringReader(s);
                    }
                })
                .decoder(new Decoder<String, Reader>() {
                    @Override
                    public Reader decode(Event type, String s) {
                        if (type.equals(Event.MESSAGE)) {
                            System.out.println("---- Message received ----");
                            System.out.println("---- Date and time: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString() + " ----");
                        }
                        System.out.println("Decode: " + s);
                        return new StringReader(s);
                    }
                })
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET)                        // Try WebSocket
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.LONG_POLLING);                    // Fallback to Long-Polling

        final OptionsBuilder<DefaultOptions, DefaultOptionsBuilder> clientOptions = client.newOptionsBuilder()
                .reconnect(true)
                .pauseBeforeReconnectInSeconds(60);

        final Socket socket = client.create(clientOptions.build());

        try {
            socket.on("message", new Function<String>() {
                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Respuesta: " + s);
                }
            }).on(new Function<IOException>() {

                @Override
                public void on(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).on(Event.CLOSE.name(), new Function<String>() {

                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Se ha perdido la conexión con el servidor.");
                    try {
                        socket.open(request.build(), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).on(Event.ERROR, new Function<String>() {

                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + s);
                    System.out.println("Se ha perdido la conexión con el servidor.");
                    try {
                        socket.open(request.build(), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).on(Event.REOPENED.name(), new Function<String>() {

                @Override
                public void on(String s) {
                    System.out.println("Reconexión.");
                }
            }).open(request.build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I have a repo case available at https://github.com/hecnabae/jerseyAtmosphere